How to make network settings permanent?
I have Ubuntu 24.04 and a local network. I try to configure in the Network settings a wired connection with manual IPv4 mode, static IP address, I apply it and it works, but after a while it is still trying to get an address through DHCP. I reopen the network dialog and it came back to Automatic (DHCP), though my static address still works. Restarting didn't change anything. It's like "Apply" is not saving my settings.
After many tries to reconnect through DHCP, it gives up and disables the connection, rendering the static IP unusable.
I tried also creating a configuration file in /etc/netplan/ or editing /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml, but to no avail, same behavior.

Try this:
Find out how your ethernet card is identified
Running:
         ip add
         

Suppose it is enp0s2
Now configure the 00-installer-config.yaml file
Run:
         sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
         
         

It will have content similar to this
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s2:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2

Modify the contents of the file, using your own parameters, so that it looks similar to the following, use your own values, not the ones in the example.
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
 ethernets:
  enp0s2:
     addresses:
     - 192.168.100.110/24
     dhcp4: false
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: 192.168.100.1
     nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
  version: 2

Ctrl + O, save the file
Ctrl + X, close nano
To apply the changes run
sudo netplan apply
        
         


I don't have that file. I have 01-network-manager-all.yaml, 50-cloud-init.yaml, and some twenty-something 99-NM-*, with different IDs.

I grepped the name of my ethernet card in those 99-NM-* files and found the one that keeps its configuration. I added dhcp4: false, and it seems that did the trick, thank you!
